# javascript countdown drift

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I have been coding a penny auction site and running into a problem with the countdowns. The starting time seems to be a little different on different machines (usually a discrepancy of about a second, but sometimes 2 or 3), which obviously is a big issue for bidders. I'm thinking a big part of the answer is simply network lag, but (a) are there other factors involved? and (b) is there a way to correct for network lag somehow?

I've tried hitting the server via an Ajax call every second, and that works well enough (though there's always a bit of lag) but I'd rather not have to do that because it'll be hard on the server.

JavaScript development is not my forte, so I'd appreciate any tips and feedback!

Here's my code, as generated on the server

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var aid = " . $aid . ";
var loadTime = Math.floor(jQuery.now()/1000);
//alert(loadTime);
serverTime = " . time() . ";
var clockDiff = loadTime - serverTime;
var diff;
auctionExpirationValue" . $aid . " = " . $expiry . ";
    var newServerTime = setInterval(function() {
         diff = window['auctionExpirationValue' + aid] - Math.floor((jQuery.now())/1000) + clockDiff;
         diff_string = parse_countdown(diff);
         jQuery('#auction-expiry').html(diff_string);
    },1000);
});
```

the clockDiff variable is to account for any clock differences between the user's machine and the server. Obviously, if one machine is ahead or behind the user would see different values in the countdown.

As you can see, the code loops every second (or, more or less every second, I understand it's not exact), calculates the difference between now and the auction expiry (compensating with clockDiff), formats it and displays it. Pretty simple. The auctionExpirationValue*** global variable is used to store the auction expiry time locally as a timestamp.

My client has also informed me that on his iPad, the countdown would sometimes drift a little, in addition to the original discrepancy. What's the explanation there?

Comment: Don't hit it every second, you can hit is every 30 seconds/minute etc.

Comment: That would help, but I'd rather not have to hit the server at all after the page is loaded.

Comment: Well only way to make sure that you did not drift really far will require a check. intervals and timeouts are not the most accurate thing in the world. Add in network latency and you will be off.

Comment: True. Okay, a mixed approach does sound like the best plan.